# Operación que no espera por su finalización para realizar une otra misma operación

Tags: java, hilos

He encontrado una cosa muy interessante : tengo un programa en java que hace operaciones sobre un cuenta. Hace operación cero hasta el cuenta esta differente de 0. Sin embargo hay un momento durante no funciona este `operaciónCero(int cantidad)` aunque utlizo `synchronized`. Porque eso esta tan importante utilizarlo?

```
public class Cuenta {
    private int solde=0;    
    public void ajouter(int cantidad){
        solde=solde+cantidad;
        System.out.println(" adición de " +cantidad);
    }

    public void retirer (int cantidad){
        solde=solde-cantidad;
        System.out.println(" retirada de " +cantidad);
    }

    public synchronized void operaciónCero (int cantidad){

        solde=solde+somme;
        System.out.print(" adición de " +cantidad +",");
        solde=solde-cantidad;
        System.out.print("et retirada de " +cantidad +".");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public synchronized int getSolde(){
        return solde;
    }
}
```

Esta llamada por esta clase :

```
public class Operation extends Thread {
    private Cuenta compte;    
    public Operation(String nom, Cuenta compte){
        super(nom);
        this.compte=compte;    
    }    
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            int i= (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            String nom=this.getName();
            System.out.print(nom);

            this.compte.operaciónCero(i)


            int montant=this.compte.getSolde(); 
            if (montant !=0){
                System.out.println(nom +"solde =" +montant);
                System.exit(1);
            } 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Compte c = new Compte();
        for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
            Operation op= new Operation("op"+i,c);
            op.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sin saber cómo llamas a tus métodos no podemos saber dónde está el fallo y si hace falta sincronizar más bloques de código. Deberías poner que error tienes, haciendo qué y de dónde salen tus variables (por ejemplo `somme`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no usas bloques sincronizados para acceder a una propiedad de la instancia debes sincronizar TODOS los métodos que hagan cualquier tipo de operación sobre ella:

```
public class Cuenta {
    private int solde = 0;

    public synchronized void ajouter(int cantidad) {
        solde += cantidad;
        System.out.println(" adición de " + cantidad);
    }

    public synchronized void retirer (int cantidad) {
        solde -= cantidad;
        System.out.println(" retirada de " +cantidad);
    }

    public synchronized void operaciónCero (int cantidad) {
        solde += cantidad;
        System.out.print(" adición de " + cantidad + ",");
        solde -= cantidad;
        System.out.print("et retirada de " + cantidad + ".");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public synchronized int getSolde(){
        return solde;
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, tenías un bug con el nombre del parámetro que sumabas en `operaciónCero` (¿quizá no copiaste/pegaste tu código real y trataste de traducirlo al castellano?).

Sólo sincronizando TODOS los métodos que acceden o modifican dicha propiedad te aseguras consistencia en su valor. Te habías dejado `ajouter` y `retirer` sin sincronizar, si durante tu prueba usas dichos métodos para modificar el valor de `solde` podrías obtener resultados inesperados.

En cuanto a la prueba que haces, si sólo llamas a `operaciónCero` para hacer el test y `getSolde` para comprobar el valor de `solde` no deberías tener un bloqueo permanente (realmente no he entendido qué tipo de bloqueo o error es el que sufres).

Comment: Todo esto está bien, yo solamente cambiaría una cosa: marca `solde` como `volatile` y quita el `synchronized` de `getSolde`. Con eso haces la lectura más eficiente porque N hilos pueden leer el valor simultáneamente.

Comment: Correcto. Gracias por matizar ese detalle :) básicamente `volatile` impide cualquier optimización o caché local sobre el contenido de la variable y a efectos prácticos es como si hubiera un `synchronized` que cubre únicamente la instrucción en la que haces uso de ella.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de `int`, usa un `AtomicInteger`. Esa clase tiene operaciones atómicas para incrementar y decrementar el valor de un entero, es ideal para tu caso.